# Cannot understand how this solution to an online judge can be wrong

Tags: java

[Here is the question from the online judge](https://open.kattis.com/problems/anothercandies)

I am trying to solve what seems to be a relatively simple problem, given an input the number of children, and the total number of sweets there are, print "YES" if the sweets can be divided equally among the kids otherwise print "NO".

As you can see from the image, the first two test cases pass and the last one does not. I am scratching my head here, any ideas?

[image]

```
import java.util.*;
public class AnotherCandies {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int cases = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
        {
            long numKids = sc.nextLong();
            long total = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < numKids; j++)
            {
                long n = sc.nextLong();
                total += n;
            }

            if(total % numKids == 0)
                System.out.println("YES");
            else
                System.out.println("NO");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know what the test case is?

Comment: No, i only know the two that I have passed, the last one is hidden

Comment: It might be testing for some corner/invalid case like negative input or something similar.

Comment: It's probably trying edge cases. Maybe its trying with 0 candies so `0 % numKids` will be true.

Comment: Without knowing what the test case is, we cannot help you.

Comment: It's probably trying with very large numbers of candies. It mentions that each child has less than 2^63 candies, but Long.MAX_VALUE is just 2^63-1. So if two children each have Long.MAX_VALUE candies your code has a nice Long overflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with sum of long overload. You could use `%` at each step and then do it again for the final sum:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        for (int i = 0, T = scan.nextInt(); i < T; i++) {
            int N = scan.nextInt();
            int sum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                sum = (int)(scan.nextLong() % N + sum) % N;

            System.out.println(N == 0 ? "YES" : "NO");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, usually kattis will give you an error for this, or so i thought, can you tell me why you declared the scanner in a try? thanks again

Comment: `Scanner` is an external resource and it should be closed.

Answer (score -2):

i think you need to put check for case `total=0`. Maybe it that case u should print No?

```
if(total == 0)
     System.out.println("NO");
else if(total % numKids == 0)
     System.out.println("YES");
else
     System.out.println("NO");
```

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Why? I provided corner case. When you dont have any candies it doesnt mean you can share it between kids equal